# Quick steps to use C code with Java

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm working on a game that has simple pixel-art sprites. Since I'm planning to do it scalable (I mean the whole game graphics scales) I would like to implement a good scaling algorithm suited for pixel-art, searching around internet I found this [HQX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hqx) so that I can scale all the sprites (not in real-time) and then use these new versions.

I found the implementation of this HQX algorithm in C code, everything reduces to a simple function that takes the `uint32_t` array of the source image and fills a new `uint32_t` array already allocated with the scaled version of the sprite.

The signature is just

```
HQX_API void HQX_CALLCONV hq2x_32( uint32_t * sp, uint32_t * dp, int Xres, int Yres )
```

where the two symbols are declared as

```
#if defined( __GNUC__ )
    #ifdef __MINGW32__
        #define HQX_CALLCONV __stdcall
    #else
        #define HQX_CALLCONV
    #endif
#else
    #define HQX_CALLCONV
#endif

#if defined(_WIN32)
    #ifdef DLL_EXPORT
        #define HQX_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define HQX_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define HQX_API
#endif
```

So that the target can be build as standalone or library.

What I would like to do is to invoke this method from Java thorugh JNI. Which tasks should I accomplish to do it? In addition I would like to know if the performance would be an issue or not, I don't think so since, also if JNI call is expensive, just a call is done for every sprite (but it possibly requires a lot of memory to be copied back and forth from JVM and native code).

I know both languages (Java and C), so I just need to know the steps involved in doing this task, assuming it's enough simple, otherwise I'll just take the JNI reference and study it..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you convert the C code into Java? It's possible there is very little work in the conversion, unless pointers are involved.

Comment: I thought about that, that's why I asked for steps.. to measure how much effort will I have to spend to interface Java with existing code instead that translating it directly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are scaling the sprites infrequently, you may find it easier to work with [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) (Java Native Access) than JNI. It's much friendlier, but slower. With JNA, you may not need to write any additional native code.

If you do use JNI, typically you'll create "native methods" in Java (empty methods with a "native" qualifier"), use javah to generate a C header file, and write a corresponding C source file to implement the "native method." At runtime, you'll need to load your native library with [System.loadLibrary()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29). (If you're on a Mac, the dynamic library extension must be .jnilib.)

JNI calls can be measured in nanoseconds. Large arrays might be copied, increasing that time. Earlier this year I measured it at about 80 microseconds for 100,000 element array of ints. I think that can be avoided with the java.io type DirectByteBuffer.

Comment: Actually it is something that is done just once per sprite at application startup and never more, I'll check about JNA in a short, thanks in the meanwhile :)

Comment: Will I have to provide a different compiled thing for every platform? I think yes with JNI, not sure with JNA since I don't know what it is yet..

Comment: You can provide a single compilation of the Java code, but you'll need different native libraries for different platforms. With JNI, yes, you'll need a native library for the implementation of your JNI native methods, plus whatever native libraries are required for HQX. With JNA you might not require any native library other than those you obtain or build for HQX.